# I Dont know whats wrong with this code

Tags: python, random

So I want this code to pick a random item from each list in the order of list1 to list2 to list3. Then I want it to put them into a randomly generated sentence:

```
from random import randint

list1 = ["Artless", "Bawdy", "Bootless"]

list2 = ["Base-court", "Bat-fowling", "Beetle-headed"]

list3 = ["Apple-john", "Baggage", "Bladder"]

import random

def nurd3(): 
  print (random.choice(list1))

def nurd2():
    print (random.choice(list2))

def nurd1(): 
   print (random.choice(list3))


print ("Thou" + nurd1() + nurd2() + nurd3())
```

Comment: you're printing, not returning. so the function calls will print out their word, return nothing, then you print out the `thou` string...

Comment: Please do include the output you got and what you expected instead. Many programmers can *guess* at what your problems are, but without a clear problem statement, your question in not useful to others.

Answer (score 4):

You need to `return` instead of `print` in each function

```
def nurd3(): 
  return random.choice(list1)

def nurd2():
    return random.choice(list2)

def nurd1(): 
   return random.choice(list3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your functions are printing items, not returning strings so you can't use them to concatenate the string in the last print.  Those functions all return `None`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is you are confusing **printing** values from a function with **returning** values from a function.

When you **print** the value, the value is simply printed to the interpreter.  When you **return** the value, the function call evaluates to that value, which is what you want.

So, instead of

```
def nurd3(): 
  print (random.choice(list1))
```

use this

```
def nurd3(): 
  return (random.choice(list1))
```

Also note that you're going to want spaces around the words.  The best way to accomplish that is this:

```
print ("Thou {n1} {n2} {n3}".format(n1=nurd1(), n2=nurd2(), n3=nurd3()))
```